# How to get querystring parameters from endpoint in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am create simple node server with multiple endpoints and want to pass the querystring into endpoints. Though i am able to create the endpoints successfully, i am not able to get the querystring value in the endpoint. Here is the sample code i am using : -

```
const http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require("fs");
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var data = fs.readFileSync('HolidaysList.json');
    let holidays = JSON.parse(data);
    res.statusCode = 200;
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
    let month = url_parts.query.month;
    console.log(month);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    if (req.url === '/') {
        res.end('Holiday List.\n');
    } else if (req.url === '/public') {
        res.end('Public Holiday List.\n');
        console.log(holidays.public);
    }
    else if (req.url === '/flexible') {
        res.end('Flexible Holiday List.\n');
        console.log(holidays.flexible);
    }
}).listen(port, hostname);
console.log('Server running at http://' + hostname + ':' + port + '/');
```

I want to process the request with /public?month=May query-string.

Comment: Since you are not using any http framework like Express that has queryString parsing built-in, you will have to parse the queryString out of the URL yourself.  There are multiple ilbraries built-into node.js to hep you such as the `url` and `querystring` modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [query-string](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) module provided along with Node JS to parse and retrieve query parameters. querystring has function called parse which will convert the query into a object that you could do something with according to your needs.

```
const http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require("fs");
const querystring = require('querystring'); // Require the querystring module
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var data = fs.readFileSync('HolidaysList.json');
    let holidays = JSON.parse(data);
    res.statusCode = 200;
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
    let month = url_parts.query.month;
    console.log(month);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    if (req.url === '/') {
        // Use querystring.parse() to retrieve query string params
        const queryParams = queryString.parse(req.query)
        console.log(queryParams)
        res.end('Holiday List.\n');
    } else if (req.url === '/public') {
        res.end('Public Holiday List.\n');
        console.log(holidays.public);
    }
    else if (req.url === '/flexible') {
        res.end('Flexible Holiday List.\n');
        console.log(holidays.flexible);
    }
}).listen(port, hostname);
console.log('Server running at http://' + hostname + ':' + port + '/');
```